# Support of SP2010 Workflow in Sharepoint Online

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, 2010, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

Is it known how long SP2010 Workflows are supported in Sharepoint Online environment?

Currently, we are migrating to SP2010 to SPO. We have a lot of WF running on SP2010, however, we have less time to rebuild everything to a SP2013 WF.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Actually,** There is no frank support end date for `SharePoint Workflow 2010 platform!`

**However,** the support end date for the **SharePoint Designer 2013** that used to create `Sharepoint 2010 workflows` is **7/14/2026**,

> Check also [SharePoint Designer 2016 and InfoPath 2016 in SharePoint
>   Server 2016, What’s the alternatives?](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/05/06/did-you-consider-powerapps-is-a-replacement-for-sharepoint-designer-and-infopath-in-sharepoint/)

---

So I advise you to plan to move all SP 2010 workflows to the  **Microsoft Flow**, instead of the `SharePoint 2013 workflow platform` that its support end date is **1/10/2023**

> Check also the product lifecycle support date at [Microsoft product
>   lifecycle](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search?alpha=Workflow%20Manager%201.0)

Comment: Hi Mohamed, could you please share Microsoft official article or blog where these support end dates are mentioned for both SharePoint 2010 & 2013 workflow platform?

Comment: Hello @ZakirHC Have you checked  the product lifecycle support link, it's very helpful for all MS products https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/hub/4095338/microsoft-lifecycle-policy

Comment: This needs to be updated